# weird error on deleting a variable

Tags: c++

So I got a class A and class B where class A is the base class of class B. However when I do something like this:

```
int main()
{
   B der(222);
   A* test;
   test = &der;
   delete test;
}
```

I got an error:

```
debug assertion failed!

program:.......
line 52 

Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead0>nBlockUse)
```

any idea?

Comment: `der` has automatic storage. It will be de-allocated automatically. Calling `delete` on its address is illegal (and causes undefined behaviour).

Comment: Every delete should be countered with a new. Use both or neither.

Comment: @smithNeil: Please upvote and accept (one of) the below answers when you've gotten the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `delete` on a variable that you didn't manually allocate memory for.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `der` is not a dynamically allocated object. ie, it is not allocated using `new`. So you should not use `delete` on that object. `der` object would be automatically destroyed once it goes out of scope. If you want to use `delete`, then you should create the object using `new`

```
A * test = new B(222);
delete test;
```